# Python - Fastest way to find all perfect squares in a given large number range

Tags: python-3.x, square-root, perfect-square

I am trying to write a method to **get all the perfect squares in a given range in Python**. A large range like between 2621163 and 520001400002. Now obviously iterating through the range and checking if a number is perfect like so

```
def is_square(n):
    return math.sqrt(n).is_integer()
```

and then printing it is stupid for large ranges (works great for small ranges) and will take forever. I am wondering if there is any Python magic or mathemagic (say a modified Diophantine equation) that I can leverage for this purpose.

**EDIT:** Also I am using Python 3.X so I can use large integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply find the smallest and largest numbers that have squares in the specified range. Then you can return the squares of every number in that range.

```
import math

def perfect_squares(min, max):
    lowest = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(min)))
    highest = int(math.sqrt(max))
    return (n**2 for n in range(lowest, highest + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def perfect_squares(start, stop):
  return (i*i for i in xrange(math.ceil(math.sqrt(start)), math.floor(math.sqrt(stop)) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the number is 34929456, you can come to know it isn't a perfect square as when it's split up 3:4:9:2:9:4:5:6= 42. 42 isn't a square number so that means 34929456 isn't a perfect square! (I'm not using a calculator for any of this) Now we know it isn't a perfect square, you'll round it up/Down... 
So, you take the last 2 digits, 56! To make 56 with single digits is 7(Times)8=56! 34929456 is a 8 digit number so that means 8-7=1+4=5. So that means the answer is between 5000 and 6000. Now, you do a little guessing. Let's do 5500 squared=  30250000. So we know the square root is a bit bigger! Now let's try 5910. 5910 squared = 34928100. So know we know the answer is between 5910 and 5911! Thanks for reading! :P, Hope it helped!

Comment: The sum of digits of a perfect square (PS) number need not be a perfect square, e.g. 64, 256.

Answer (score 0):

## getting perfect square from 1 to 100 digit using numpy

```
import numpy as np

a={int(np.sqrt(x)) for x in range(1,101)}

b= np.power(list(a),2) 

print(a)

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple python code with out using functions

```
import math
num=500
for i in range(1,math.ceil(math.sqrt(num))):
    print(i*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You realize that if you know the first and last closest perfect square, the rest is just the range between them. I would calculate it this way:

```
import math

def all_squares(a,b):#a is the starting point whereas b is the end of range
    smallest = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(a)))#perfect square closest to lower bound (rounded up)
    largest = int(math.sqrt(b))#perfect square closest to upper bound (rounded down)
    squares = []
    for s in range(smallest, largest+1):
        squares.append(s**2)
    return squares
```